# To think a little about it VS not thinking at all

Tags: word-choice, expressions, verbs

I have found difficult to find an expression for the act when you stop your answer, think about it briefly, and then answer. EX: "Well, you know....." "I am not going to do it"

And in contrast an expression for doing something without thinking like: he talked without giving it an ounce of thought (but I am not sure if that expression is correct"

Answer (score -1):

"**On second thoughts** ..."

rarely implies that there has been  hours of deliberation on the matter.

The 'Well' in the example strongly suggests a change of decision.

'He paused for thought' is possible, but to 'give someone pause for thought' means to *really* make them think and is perhaps more common.

Comment: In the U.S., you'd say "On second thought..."